# Return multiple variables on async/await

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, es6-promise

I was wondering if there is a way to get the second `resolve` value (test2) without returning arrays or JavaScript objects.

```js
function testFunction() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    resolve("test1", "test2");
  });
}

async function run() {
  var response = await testFunction();
  console.log(response); // test1
}

run();
```

Comment: Well what would you expect `response` to become then?

Comment: I don't understand why You want to avoid returning data structure (an object) this is how JavaScript is constructed to do such things.

Comment: @MaciejSikora @Bergi, I was wondering if there was built-in functionality since both variables are available if you construct the function call without async/await: `testFunction().then(function(response1, response2) {...})`.

Comment: @MarkNijboer No they aren't. At least not with standard ES6 promises, which have a single result value only.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can pass only one item. But starting from `ES6` there is a good feature called **[Array Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).**

**Return an array and you can leave the properties assignment under the hood.**

```js
function testFunction() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
          resolve([ "test1", "test2"] );
           });
}

async function run() {

  const [firstRes, secondRes] = await testFunction();
  
  console.log(firstRes, secondRes);

}

run();
```

Comment: I just found out that `const { response1, response2 } = await testFunction();` works in Node.js 8. It is also used by the `promisify` method in the `util` module. So there is no need to return an array :-)

Comment: returning as object is not working for me. Im getting 'undefined' for both response1 and response2 in the above example. But it works when returned as an array. Any idea why? @Mark