# multiple url variable async/await axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await, axios

Probably this is a very stupid question, i'm new in Node.js and javascript, so please forgive me if the question is not properly explained or the answer is simple...

I'm trying to send 2 variables thru a url... When i send only 1 variable (artist=${term}) work all good, but I'm really stuck with about how to send 2 variables thru the url (&artist=${term1}&album=${term2})

I've work on this code so far which for 1 variable is working well... but i have no idea how to add a second or a third variable to the request:

File 1: "./services/albumInfo.js"

```
import { BRV_API } from '../../config';
import axios from 'axios';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';

const ALBUM_INFO = 'method=album.getinfo';
dotenv.config();

const doRequest = async (url) => {
    return await axios.get(`${BRV_API}/${url}&api_key=${process.env.API_KEY}&format=json`);
};

export const infoAlbum = async (term) => {
    return await doRequest(`?${ALBUM_INFO}&artist=${term}`);
};
```

File 2: "./repositories/albumInfo.js"

```
import { infoAlbum } from '../repositories/albumInfo';
import status from 'http-status';

export const albumInfo = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const { query } = req;
        
        const { data } = await infoAlbum(query.name);
        
        const response = data;

        res.status(status.OK).send(response);

    } catch (error) {

        next(error);

    }
    
};
```

I know that my problem is in this part of the code (I guess)

```
export const infoAlbum = async (term) => {
    return await doRequest(`?${ALBUM_INFO}&artist=${term1}&album=${term2}`);
};
```

I've been searching, and i've seen some solution, [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46090163/return-multiple-variables-on-async-await), but i just don't understand those solutions or how to apply on my code (sorry for that, im a very new on this)

Any good soul who can help this newbie? (if can explain the why of the solution as well, for understand, will be amazing!!)

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Also could you try to output the full url that you are using like in this picture? https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6fsj.png just to make sure

Comment: @Alex028502 I believe the issue is not in the const { data } yet; by level, the requested url is wrong. According to your picture, the output is: **"full url is /v1/infoAlbum?method=album.getinfo&artist=lenka&album=lenka&api_key=c6......b9&format=json"** is repeating the artist variable twice... how can I capture the variable album?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So,

I've found a solution, which is pretty ugly, but so far is working, if someone have a better option, will be amazing to know:

File 1: repositories/albumInfo.js, I've just add the console (as per  @Alex028502 suggestion), to know what the code was returning:

```
import { BRV_API } from '../../config';
import axios from 'axios';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';

const ALBUM_INFO = 'method=album.getinfo';
dotenv.config();

const doRequest = async (url) => {
    const fullurl = `${BRV_API}/?${ALBUM_INFO}${url}&api_key=${process.env.API_KEY}&format=json`;
    console.log('full url is', fullurl);
    return await axios.get(fullurl);
};

export const infoAlbum = async (term) => {
    return await doRequest(`&${term}`);
};
```

File 1: services/albumInfo.js: I change the behaviour of 'infoAlbum' to make the request from his side:

```
import { infoAlbum } from '../repositories/albumInfo';
import status from 'http-status';

export const albumInfo = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const { query } = req;

        console.log(query);
        
        const { data } = await infoAlbum('artist=' + query.artist + '&album=' + query.album);
        
        const response = data;

        res.status(status.OK).send(response);

    } catch (error) {

        next(error);

    }
    
};
```

I know that probably this is not the very best way to walk away from the problem, but so far is what i have.... any other better option about how to capture the second or third parameter of the url request and then add them to the final url?

Best!

Answer (score 0):

Axios provides parameters that can be added custom as the following

```
const your_url = process.env.URL
const infoAlbum = await axios.get(your_url,{
               params: { 
                    artist: term,
                    album: term2,
                    api_key: process.env.API_KEY,
                    format:'json'
               }
          })

console.log(infoAlbum.data.args)
```

note: your_url without any more parameters.

Comment: Is giving me a error:

```SyntaxError: ../src/repositories/albumInfo.js: Unexpected reserved word 'await'. (20:18)

  19 | const your_url = process.env.URL
> 20 | const infoAlbum = await axios.get(your_url,{
     |                   ^
  21 |                params: { 
  22 |                     method: 'album.getinfo',
  23 |                     artist: term,
    at Parser._raise (../node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/error.js:134:45)
   
  loc: Position { line: 20, column: 18 },
  pos: 634,
  code: 'BABEL_PARSE_ERROR',
  reasonCode: 'UnexpectedReservedWord'
}
```

Comment: BTW, my node version: "node --version => v14.17.1" (i've seen that this issue is commonly due old version of node, but is not my case).

Comment: you can write it without 'await', 'await' is used in an async function